# How to disable auto focus (select) nb-select first option?

Tags: javascript, angular, nebular

When open nb-option-list first option is selected (or focused). I must be disable this function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can select a disabled option

```
<option selected disabled>Selected and disabled</option>
```

Or you can add a hidden option in first position

```
<option hidden>First item</option>
```